# List<T> object convert error in Firestore

Tags: c#, firebase, .net-core, google-cloud-firestore, asp.net-core-mvc

I try a custom list property in document. But I get an error.

Description: I have a class and subclass for create a team. When I fill this class and add them to firestore, it give an error some like below. But if I'm not add any info for subclass,It become successfull. I try List, FsTeamMembers[], Dictionary but always same issue. I didn't find anything about that.

*Note: I try "Google.Cloud.Firestore" 1.1.0 and 2.1.0 versions and my project .net core 3.1*

Main Model:

```cs
[Serializable]
public class FsTeamsModel
{
  public string documentId { get; set; }
  public string teamName { get; set; }
  public Guid teamCode { get; set; }
  public DateTimeOffset createDate { get; set; }
  public string teamOwner { get; set; }
  // public FsTeamMembers[] teamMembers { get; set; }
  public Dictionary<string, FsTeamMembers> teamMembers { get; set; }
}
```

Sub Model:

```cs
[Serializable]
public class FsTeamMembers
{
   public string email { get; set; }
   public DateTimeOffset addedDate { get; set; }
}
```

Add method:

```cs
var db = FirestoreDb.Create(projectId);
var collectionRef = db.Collection(collectionName);
DocumentReference documentRef;
var jsonSerializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings
   {
     DateTimeZoneHandling = DateTimeZoneHandling.Utc,
     DateFormatHandling = DateFormatHandling.IsoDateFormat,
     DateParseHandling = DateParseHandling.DateTimeOffset,
     ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore,
     NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore
   };
var serializedParticipant = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(fsAddModel.Document,jsonSerializerSettings);
var addDocument = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, object>>(serializedParticipant,jsonSerializerSettings);

documentRef = collectionRef.Document(); 
addDocument["documentId"] = documentRef.Id;


await documentRef.SetAsync(addDocument);
```

Error:

```cs
at Google.Cloud.Firestore.Converters.ConverterCache.CreateConverter(Type targetType)
at Google.Cloud.Firestore.Converters.ConverterCache.<>c.<GetConverter>b__1_0(Type t)
at System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2.GetOrAdd(TKey key, Func`2 valueFactory)
at Google.Cloud.Firestore.Converters.ConverterCache.GetConverter(Type targetType)
at Google.Cloud.Firestore.SerializationContext.GetConverter(Type targetType)
at Google.Cloud.Firestore.ValueSerializer.Serialize(SerializationContext context, Object value)
at Google.Cloud.Firestore.Converters.DictionaryConverter`1.SerializeMap(SerializationContext context, Object value,IDictionary`2 map)
at Google.Cloud.Firestore.Converters.MapConverterBase.Serialize(SerializationContext context, Object value)
at Google.Cloud.Firestore.ValueSerializer.Serialize(SerializationContext context, Object value)
at Google.Cloud.Firestore.Converters.DictionaryConverter`1.SerializeMap(SerializationContext context, Object value,IDictionary`2 map)
at Google.Cloud.Firestore.Converters.MapConverterBase.Serialize(SerializationContext context, Object value)
at Google.Cloud.Firestore.ValueSerializer.Serialize(SerializationContext context, Object value)
at Google.Cloud.Firestore.Converters.DictionaryConverter`1.SerializeMap(SerializationContext context, Object value,IDictionary`2 map)
at Google.Cloud.Firestore.ValueSerializer.SerializeMap(SerializationContext context, Object value)
at Google.Cloud.Firestore.WriteBatch.Set(DocumentReference documentReference, Object documentData, SetOptionsoptions)
at Google.Cloud.Firestore.DocumentReference.SetAsync(Object documentData, SetOptions options, CancellationTokencancellationToken)
```

Edit 1: example json

I don't have any json, because I'm not add any value, but It must seem like this

```
{
    "docuemntId": "docuemntid",
    "teamName": "A name",
    "teamCode": "GUID",
    "createdDate": "2020-05-04", //Example Date
    "teamOwner": "Owner Name",
    "teamMembers": [
        {
            "email": "email@example.com",
            "addedDate": "2020-05-09"
        },
        {
            "email": "email@example.com",
            "addedDate": "2020-06-01"
        }
    ]
}
```

Edit 2: Firestore data example

I create an example data with console.

I show each property and types

[image: list]

Edit 3: I notice something. If I change teamMembers property from Dictionary to Array. I can read document which I created in console

[image: firestore to c#]

Comment: Can you add either the json that you are reading?

Comment: @Emanuele I don't have any json. But I added some example what I want